# XCode unit test

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, core-data

Making CoreData model with simple class Mood:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Mood: NSManagedObject {
    static let entityName = "\(Mood.self)"

    class func mood(withTitle title: String) -> Mood {
        let mood: Mood = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: Mood.entityName, into: CoreDataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext) as! Mood
        mood.title = title
        return mood
    }
}

extension Mood {
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

and writing simple unit test for that class:

```
import XCTest
@testable import DiaryApp

class DiaryAppTests: XCTestCase {
    var mood = Mood.mood(withTitle: "Happy")

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(self.mood)
    }
}
```

getting error: "Could not cast value of type 'DiaryApp.Mood' (0x6000000df730) to 'DiaryAppTests.Mood' (0x10e9ed8a8)."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing all files of my project from DiaryAppTests Compile Sources (at Build Phase tab in TARGETS)  - after that my classes were undefined in Tests. For make them defined added string "@testable import DiaryApp" before declaration of TestCase.